# Short argument for asymptotic value of parameter integral

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

> I want to find the main term of the asymptotic expansion for $x\to 0^+$ for
>
> $$f(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\cos t}{t+x}dt.$$

Now, clearly, the problem is at $t=0$ and the cosine is almost $1$ there, so I can replace the cosine with $1$ and I can find my result.

However, to justify this approach, my only tool is to use the estimation of the cosine between $1-\dfrac{t^2}2$ and $1$ in this interval for the difference between $f(x)$ and the expression where the cosine is replaced with $1$ which is ok, but not very pretty.

> What is the cleanest argument that goes from the start of the expansion of the cosine to the start of the expansion of the function $f$ without using any irrelevant calculatory details?

(I would be as happy with a link to a similar problem or an appropriate theorem or a rough sketch as with a complete solution.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\eqalign{f(x)&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{t+x} dt-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t }{t+x}dt\cr
&=\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)-\ln x-
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t }{t}dt+
\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t+x}\right)(1-\cos t )dt\cr
&=\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)-\ln x-
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t }{t}dt+x
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t}{t(t+x)}dt
}$$
Clearly, for the last integral we have
$$
0\leq \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t}{t(t+x)}dt\leq \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}dt.
$$
Also, $\ln(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)=\ln\frac{\pi}{2}+{\cal O}(x)$, combining these we conclude that, as $x\to0^+$ we have
$$
f(x)=C-\ln x+{\cal O}(x)
$$
where,
$$C=\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos t}{t}\,dt=-\gamma+\hbox{Ci}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $\hbox{Ci}$ is the CosIntegral function.
$\qquad\square$

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how much this could help you. Suppose you change variable $t=z-x$; then $$\int \dfrac{\cos t}{t+x}dt=\int \dfrac{\cos (z-x)}{z}dz=\text{Ci}(z) \cos (x)+\text{Si}(z) \sin (x)$$ where appear the sine and cosine integrals. So, going back to $t$ and computing the integral, we arrive to $$f(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\cos t}{t+x}dt=\left(\text{Ci}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\text{Ci}(x)\right) \cos
   (x)+\left(\text{Si}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\text{Si}(x)\right) \sin (x)$$ If we now consider that $x$ is small, the beginning of the corresponding Taylor series is $$f(x) \simeq\left(\text{Ci}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\gamma
   \right)- \log (x)+\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$